# How to configure Kubernetes so the failed pod did not reply to ICMP echo-requests?

Tags: kubernetes

I've noticed that even *failed* pods replays to ICMP pings ( pods in not Ready state ). Is there a way to configure CNI ( or Kubernetes ) in the way so failed pods didn't generate ICMP replies ?

```
#kubectl get pods -o wide         
NAME          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE    IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
multitool-1   1/1     Running            0          20m    172.17.0.3   minikube   <none>           <none>
multitool-2   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          20m    172.17.0.4   minikube   <none>           <none>
multitool-3   1/1     Running            0          3m9s   172.17.0.5   minikube   <none>           <none>
#kubectl exec multitool-3 -it bash
bash-5.0# ping 172.17.0.4
PING 172.17.0.4 (172.17.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.107 ms
^C
--- 172.17.0.4 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1041ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.048/0.077/0.107/0.029 ms
bash-5.0#
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not how ICMP works. The kernel handles those, it only checks if the networking interface is operational, which it is regardless of how broken the container process might be.

Comment: Thank you, I was under impression that all traffic (including icmp) get forwarded to the container NIC. It seems that icmp is treated differently ( as you said). Do you know the reason for such behavior? Also any links to the docs/source code describing subj would be highly appreciated

Comment: ICMP is, by default, entirely handled by the kernel as I said. The only way to even see ICMP packets in userspace is capture systems like libnetfilter. There is no POSIX API for "listen for ICMP" like there is for TCP and UDP.